# How to visualize > 1000 rows from MySQL Table in an HTML DataTable using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, php-7.1

I am currently hitting an AJAX Request from JS, which in turn calls my PHP API, which returns an array of JSON Objects back to my AJAX Request. Using this returned data, I am filling my HTML DataTable.

My **AJAX Request** to retrieve data from my PHP API is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../Retrievers/Retriever-DataTable-API.php",
    data: {"table_name" : table_name},
    async: true,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
          console.log(data);
          var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
          console.log(obj);
          if(obj.status == '200'){

            var counter = 0;
            var size = Object.size(obj.Data[0]['Date']);
            while(counter < size){

              //This loops 1000 times for adding New Columns to DataTable via Javascript
              table.row.add( [
                  obj.Data[0]['Date'][counter],
                  obj.Data[0]['Time'][counter],
                  obj.Data[0]['tss'][counter],
                  obj.Data[0]['milk'][counter],
                  obj.Data[0]['milk2'][counter],
                  obj.Data[0]['ac_voltage'][counter],
                  obj.Data[0]['compressor_current'][counter],
                  obj.Data[0]['discharge_pump_relay'][counter],
                  obj.Data[0]['agitator_relay'][counter],
                  obj.Data[0]['discharge2_pump_relay'][counter],
                  obj.Data[0]['agitator2_relay'][counter],
              ] ).draw( false );
              counter++;

              // Automatically add a first row of data
              $('#addRow').click();
            }
          }else {
            console.log(obj.status);
        }
    },
    error: function(){
      console.log("ajax error for data-table");
    },
}); //ajax request for DataTable ends here
```

And, my **PHP API Code** which returns JSON Array with 1000 Rows of Data pulled from MySQL Table is as follows:

```
$Table_Name = $_POST['c_name']; //Read incoming Table Name sent from AJAX Request
$query1 = "SELECT * from database1.".$Table_Name." ORDER BY TableTimeStamp DESC limit 1440;";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query1);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){

 while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){

   //This loops 1000 times to read data and insert it in JSON Array
   //Capture $TableTimeStamp and split it into Date and Time Columns
   $temp = new DateTime($row[11]);
   array_push($DateArray, $temp->format('d-m-Y'));
   array_push($TimeArray, $temp->format('H:i:s'));
   array_push($tssArray, $row[12] * $scaling_offset_for_tss);
   array_push($milkArray, $row[13] * $scaling_offset_for_milk);
   array_push($cheeseArray, $row[41] * $scaling_offset_for_cheese);

 } //while ends here

 $response = array(
  'status'=> '200',
  'Data'=>[
      array(
        'Date' => $DateArray,
        'Time' => $TimeArray,
        'tss' => $tssArray,
        'milk' => $milkArray,
        'cheese' => $cheeseArray
    )]
 );

 echo json_encode($response); //This returns Array of 1000 rows of MySQL Data back to my ajax function
} //main for ends here
```

So, basically what happens here is my first Loop runs 1000 times in PHP API, then to traverse through it and append it to Datatable, my second Loop again runs 1000 times in JavaScript.

Hence, when I load this page, it takes forever to load data in the DataTable.

Please inform me how to reduce this time, and looping 2000 times for Data retrieval.

Also, **I am planning to replace this PHP API with NodeJS API, so let me know, if anything can be done using NodeJS too.**

Comment: Please paginate your data and deliver as the user scroll the page with multiple requests.

Comment: Hi @BrunoSousa, can you explain it a bit more ? Thanks

Comment: Changing of api wont help you. Use pagination and fetch 100-200 records each time and display 10-20 records in each page also display some button to user to navigate to next and previous page. It simplifies your work and User interaction as well.

Comment: Hi @Rishaldevsingh , Thanks for your revert. Can you help me know as to how to do Pagination? Or do you know any particular Site which will explain it for me.

Comment: The trick is at the query, you should use "LIMIT" to retrieve the range you desire like: "SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15". Remember you need calculate your range based on your current page and the number of entries per page.

Comment: Please update your code including your query and the implemented pagination if you still need help.

Comment: Hi @BrunoSousa, Query which I use for MySQL is : $query1 = "SELECT * from database1.".$Table_Name." ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC limit 1440;";

Comment: @AbhayBh Update your question with the complete code and try to paginate your query by yourself first.

Comment: Hi. I have updated my Question as you said. I will try Paginating and will Let you know then.

Comment: Create an API endpoint for interfacing the database and use jQuery Datatables to paginate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Pagination Concept which Mr. Bruno Sousa and Mr. Rishal dev singh suggested, really worked out for me!

So, now I can visualize > 1000 rows in HTML5 DataTable (which is deployed using JavaScript) using my PHP-API.

For your reference: [here's a temporary link as a proof](http://52.34.21.63/dev/attempt-3/dev.html)

I have used [Server Side processing for DataTables](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) which is based on jQuery, and for the Styling Part, I have used [Bootstrap 3 Based Styling for Datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html)

Cheers! :)

Comment: you should paste your modified code here as well for others to take help :)

Comment: Hi @Rishaldevsingh, I have referenced DataTables.net (Server-Side Processing):
 https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html for handling my Pagination problem. It used JQuery. And, for the CSS and Styling Part, I am using [Bootstrap3 based DataTables](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html)

Answer (score 0):

I dont have anything as such in PHP or node.js , But i have implemented something in java and i am posting that here for your information,

```
    package com.synchrony.dev.dao;

        import java.sql.Connection;
        import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
        import java.sql.ResultSet;
        import java.sql.SQLException;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;

        import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

        import com.synchrony.framework.common.PropertyUtil;
        import com.synchrony.framework.common.SynchronyCommon;
        import com.synchrony.framework.database.AbstractDataBaseConnectionHandler; 
        import com.synchrony.framework.exception.ApplicationFatalException;  
        import com.synchrony.rishal.valueobjects.Table_8;

        public class Table_8DAO extends AbstractDataBaseConnectionHandler<Table_8> {
        public List<Table_8> select(ServletContext context) throws ApplicationFatalException {
            Connection conn = this.getConnection(context);
            List<Table_8> dataFetchedFromDB = new ArrayList<Table_8>();
            try {
                int pageNumber = 1;
                if (null != context.getAttribute(SynchronyCommon.PAGE_NUM)) {
                    pageNumber = Integer.parseInt((String) context.getAttribute(SynchronyCommon.PAGE_NUM));
                }
//Query to fetch according to the page number and frame size.
                PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
                        "SELECT * FROM(SELECT a.*, rownum r1 FROM(SELECT * FROM Table_8) a WHERE rownum < ((? * ?) + 1 )) WHERE r1 >= (((?-1) * ?) + 1)");
//The below value is used to fetch 10 records in each db call. you can increase this value to any 20/50/100.
                int numberOfRecordsFetchedInOneCall = Integer
                        .valueOf(PropertyUtil.getProperty(SynchronyCommon.LIST_OF_RECORDS_IN_PAGINATED, context));
                ps.setInt(2, numberOfRecordsFetchedInOneCall);
                ps.setInt(4, numberOfRecordsFetchedInOneCall);
                ps.setLong(1, pageNumber);
                ps.setInt(3, pageNumber);
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                if (!rs.isBeforeFirst()) {
                    if (pageNumber < 1) {
                        pageNumber++;
                        ps.setLong(1, pageNumber);
                        ps.setInt(3, pageNumber);
                        rs = ps.executeQuery();
                        context.setAttribute(SynchronyCommon.PAGE_NUM, pageNumber);
                        context.setAttribute(SynchronyCommon.ERROR_MESSAGE, "No More records present");
                    } else {
                        pageNumber--;
                        ps.setLong(1, pageNumber - 1);
                        ps.setInt(3, pageNumber - 1);
                        rs = ps.executeQuery();
                        context.setAttribute(SynchronyCommon.PAGE_NUM, pageNumber);
                        context.setAttribute(SynchronyCommon.ERROR_MESSAGE, "No More records present");
                    }

                } else {
                    context.setAttribute(SynchronyCommon.PAGE_NUM, pageNumber);
                    context.setAttribute(SynchronyCommon.ERROR_MESSAGE, null);

                }
                while (rs.next()) {
                    Table_8 temp = new Table_8();
                    temp.setTitle((String) rs.getString(1));
                    temp.setPlatform((String) rs.getString(2));
                    temp.setScore((double) rs.getDouble(3));
                    temp.setGenre((String) rs.getString(4));
                    temp.setEditorsChoice((String) rs.getString(5));
                    dataFetchedFromDB.add(temp);
                }

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new ApplicationFatalException(e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
            } finally {
                if (null != conn)
                    closeConnection(conn);
            }

            return dataFetchedFromDB;
        }
        }
```

use the returned data i.e. `dataFetchedFromDB` in html accordingly.

You can achieve so in similar fashion by invoking the same query which i used in your required technical stack and use the returned data as per your needs.